# How to test Menu

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit

I need to cover Menu functionality by unit tests, however I'm struggling to obtain Menu object.

Following test case fails (mMenu is null):

```
sendKeys(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU);
mMenu = (Menu) mActivity.findViewById(com.###.###.R.id.main_menu);
assertNotNull(mMenu);
```

Please advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I ran into this same scenario and came up with the following (very simple) solution in my implementation of ActivityInstrumentationTestCase:

```
...
ActivityMonitor am = getInstrumentation().addMonitor(LoginActivity.class.getName(), null, false);

// Click the menu option
getInstrumentation().sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU);
getInstrumentation().invokeMenuActionSync(mActivity, R.id.logout, 0);

Activity a = getInstrumentation().waitForMonitorWithTimeout(am, 1000);
assertEquals(true, getInstrumentation().checkMonitorHit(am, 1));
a.finish();
...
```

This snippet of code does three things:

1. Clicks the menu option,
2. Ensures we go to the appropriate activity after the menu option is clicked, and
3. finishes the activity that was started (very important for the tests following this one).

I hope this helps.

Comment: This was a useful answer and code snippet, most importantly it highlights that you have to send the 'KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU' first before invoking the menu action. In hindsight it's obvious I guess - you have to have the menu showing before you can invoke one it's items.

Comment: FWIW I use getInstrumentation().invokeMenuActionSync() without prior call to sendKeyDownUpSync() and it works just fine as well. See the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209154/test-menu-items

Comment: I observed that the call to sendKeyDownUpSync is necessary, if you want to test if, under conditions that are the result of work done in onPrepareOptionMenu, invokeMenuActionSync returns true. Without the call, onPrepareOptionsMenu was not invoked.

Answer (score 2):

What exactly are you trying to test? That menu items do the correct action?

You can call Activity.openOptionsMenu() to open the menu and get a reference to the menu by overriding one of the onMenu methods. At that point you can use Menu.performIdentifierAction to select menu items.

Comment: Yes, I need to check that all menu and sub-menu items are doing correct actions.

sendKeys(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) works correctly and I can see Menu on emulator (I can't see it if I call Activity.openOptionsMenu()).

Do you mean I need to override onMenuOpened in target app and save Menu reference inside of activity?
Maybe there is a way to not touch target application?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do UI, system or function tests I would recommend you to use Robotium. Then you can just use sendKey(Solo.MENU) and then click on the menu items by using clickOnText() or clickOnView(). When you have done that you can assert right behaviour. Just asserting that it should not be null is not enough. You should check Robotium out, its way more appropriate to use when testing things like this.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Activity act =launchActivity(intent);

    MenuBuilder builder=new MenuBuilder(mInst.getTargetContext());

    act.onCreateOptionsMenu(builder);



    act.onPrepareOptionsMenu(builder);

    Log.i(TAG, "BuilderSize: "+builder.size());
    int visible=0;
    for(int i=0;i<builder.size();i++)
    {
        MenuItem item=builder.getItem(i);

        if(item.isVisible()&& item.isEnabled())
        {
            Log.i(TAG, item.getTitle().toString());
            visible++;
        }
    }
    act.finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use instrumentation to test the pressing of the menu item for you.

Here is a sample test case of mine that invokes the "Settings" menu, which starts another activity.

```
public void testCanGoToSettings() {
    final MainActivity activity = getActivity();

    Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor am = getInstrumentation().addMonitor(ConfigureActivity.class.getName(),
            null /* result */, true /* block */);

    getInstrumentation().sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU);
    getInstrumentation().invokeMenuActionSync(activity, R.id.menu_settings, 0 /* flags */);

            /* if not block in addMonitor() above, then comment out this...
    Activity a = getInstrumentation().waitForMonitorWithTimeout(am, 1000);
    a.finish();
            */ 

}
```